# How to write in the google spread sheet specific cell using the python?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am reading the google spreadsheet and want to write back to the same sheet in a specific cell. Below is the code I have written.

```
 RANGE_NAME = 'Latest Records!A2:L'
 result = 
 service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, 
 range=RANGE_NAME).execute()
 values = result.get('values', [])

 testurl = (row[1])
    import requests
    from HomebellAutomation.System.Config import myconfig

    testurl= myconfig.URL_webpagetest

    r=requests.get( myconfig.URL_webpagetest + "?url=" + testurl + "&f=xml&k=" + myconfig.apikey_webpagetest )

    xmltxt=r.content

    #print (xmltxt)

    testId = XML (xmltxt).find("data").find('testId')

    print (testId.text)

    test_id = [testId.text]
```

I want to print the test_id back to the google spraedsheet    , Please help me on this.

Comment: What have you tried? What is not working?

Comment: You might want to check the documentation on how to [write to sheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing). You have to set the range of the specific cell and `'values':test_id` for the content of the cell.